# Examples of vector spaces that somehow generate bigger linear spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

I am used to work with vector spaces that have a basis of the same dimension. For example, in quantum mechanics one can always represent the Hamiltonian in some basis (of dimension $n$), diagonalize it (suppose that the spectrum is no degenerate), and then take the set of eigenvectors as another good basis (again of dimension $n$).

I have, however, the following Lemmas on which I want to formulate my question.

> L1. Suppose that the vectors $x_1,\dots,x_n$ span the linear space $X$ and that te vectors $y_1,\dots,y_j$ in $X$ are linearly independent. Then $j\leq n$
>
> L2. A linear space $X$ which is spanned by a finite set of vectors $x_1,\dots,x_n$ has a basis.

My first question is that if I can have a linear space $X$ of dimension $\operatorname{dim}X$, s.t. it can be spanned by $m$ vectors with $m\geq\operatorname{dim}X$. This can never happen in $\mathbb{R}^n$ right? In this case, we always have (from L1) that $n=j$.

Comment: The dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of *any* basis.  Equivalently, the dimension is the infimal cardinality of any spanning set, or the supremal cardinality of any linearly independent set.  That this notion of dimension is well-defined is an elementary (though not entirely trivial) result in the modern study of algebra.  What this means is that *any* two bases of any particular vector space must have the same cardinality.

Comment: @XanderHenderson That is not correct. In the question it is not stated that the vectors are linearly independent. The set may not be a basis hence may have a larger cardinality.

Comment: Look at the first question, I am asking for the spanning of vectors to be greater than the dimension of the linear space. That two basis has always the same dimension is  a theorem. Also the response below goes correctly to the point.

Comment: @Levent Hence the inclusion of the characterization of the dimension as the infimal cardinality of a spanning set.  If you have a spanning set, you can always through more elements in and still span the space.  Though perhaps I have having trouble parsing the question...

Comment: @XanderHenderson I believe that the question is about the generator sets alone, without considering any linear independence or so, but of course you are right about everything you say on bases of a vector space.

Comment: @Levent As I read the question (in the last paragraph), the questioner wants to know if it is possible to have a spanning set of cardinality greater than the dimension.  Since the dimension is the infimal cardinality of a spanning set, the answer will (generally) be to just throw more things in.  He then asked "This can never happen in $\mathbb{R}^n$ right?" To which the answer is "No, it can happen in $\mathbb{R}^n$."  I realize that the double negative was confusing, and edited it out above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it also happens in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider all the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is uncountably many, then they span $\mathbb{R}^n$. The thing is that a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ can be spanned by $n$ (necessarily linearly independent) vectors, but it can also be spanned by more than $n$ (necessarily linearly dependent) vectors.

Edit : Simple example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the set $\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$. When you have the first two, then you don't need the third one. But these three vectors still span $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is $2$-dimensional.